# C# Saving files on different PC's

Tags: c#, xml

The program I am writing is a stock inventory system.

So the PC I wrote the program on can locate the files and folders to update on the PC as necessary as the path is valid.

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\ThisPC\\Documents\\Stock Documents\\Reciepts";

if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Users\\ThisPC\\Documents\\Stock Documents\\Reciepts")) 
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path); 
}

var fileName = @"c:\Users\ThisPC\Documents\Stock Documents\Tyre_File.xml";
```

This line is also used when I am updating quantities when an order is taken.
So obviously when I run this program in visual studio on another PC this path isn't recognized.

Is there a way that I can add a pointer to create and store my folder and documents in the My Documents on any pc the program loads in?

**UPDATE-------------------------------------------------------**

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\ThisPC\\Documents\\Stock Documents\\Customer Reciepts";


            if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Users\\ThisPC\\Documents\\Stock Documents\\Customer Reciepts")) 
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path); 
            }
```

This is the only one it wont work for, it creates a folder within a folder when the form is loaded, but your method doesnt work for that?

Comment: After the update I do not understand what seems to be the problem. Could  you clarify a little more?
From the code I get that you want to create the directory described by path if it does not exist

Comment: Ok so the code after the update works if it is left as is. However when I run the program on another PC that path won't exist obviously. 

When I try to use the method suggested it does create the Receipt folder within the Stock Documents folder. So if I put 

`code  string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            
            if (!Directory.Exists(path + "\\Stock Documents\\Reciepts")) 
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\Stock Documents\\Reciepts"); 
            } `code`

Then it won't create the folder

Comment: why wouldn't it create the folder when using the code in the comment above?

Comment: That is what I was asking I am not sure, it should add a new folder as all the code is doing is creating a folder inside of another folder. Yet when the form loads the folder is not created.

Comment: and you are absolutely sure the folder is not the in there first place, right?

Comment: Yup I purposefully deleted the folder to see if it would be created again.

Comment: Could you try with Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)

Comment: Try using Path.Combine instead of doing + "\\Stock Documents" etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

is what you are looking for

Comment: Stuck with one last problem, I updated the problem in the original question

Answer (score 3):

You want the environment variable for MyDocuments, which will be unique for each user/computer.

```
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Comment: Stuck with one last problem, I updated the problem in the original question

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create two folders at once ('Stock Documents' and 'Customer Receipts') which I believe won't work, try creating just the 'Stock Documents' one and then the 'Customer Receipts' one after that.

Comment: No Stock documents is the main folder, with a sub folder inside of it for reciepts

Comment: If you update the original question with what your code currently looks like for creating the sub-folder, that would help